# variable replace in form in php and html

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I am trying to make a php program where user will input $name but it will replace with its variable. The code is given bellow

```
<form method="post" >
    <textarea type="text" name="preview"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="preview"></input>
<form>    
<?php
$name="Nahid";
echo $_POST['preview'];
?>
```

I am expecting an output like: My name is Nahid. 
when user will input: My name is $name.

Comment: Right, and what problem are you facing?

Comment: out put is giving $name instead variable's value

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean you want to output the value of `$name`? In which case, why are you outputting `$_POST['preview']` rather than `$name`?

Comment: I want "$name"'s variable output inside $_POST['preview'] .

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code to help achieve the stated objective of the program.

I also added some comments to help you understand the code.

I replaced `<textarea>` with an input field, and I changed the name from 'preview' to 'name' to avoid confusion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Name Preview</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action= "" method="post">
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="PREVIEW"></input>
        <form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    // Ensure that form is submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // Ensure that a name is entered
        if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']))
        {
            // Store user's input in a variable
            $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);

           // Display name
            echo "<p>";
            echo "My name is " . $name;
            echo "</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            // Display notification if no name is entered.
            echo "Please enter your name";
        }
    }
?>
```

Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you enter your name in text area and submit form so you will see entered text 
if you enter same value 'Nahid' in text area so you think $name is showing instead of $_POST['preview']
you can concat $name with $_POST['preview'] using dot
test folooowing code:

```
echo $name . ' <br> ' . $_POST['preview'];
```

please enter another name in textarea to test it